# Pandas Append/ Insert row to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

can someone tell me, why this doesn't work (series is not appended to dataframe):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 5), columns=range(1,6))
print(df)
s = df.xs(2)

s.name = 1.5
print(s)

df.append(s)
print(df)
```

no Errors occur

Comment: ```df=df.append(s)``` the function is not inplace

Comment: oof that hurts ^^

Answer (score 0):

some functions in pandas are not inplace:

```
appended_df = df.append(s)
```